# plattysoft particle system Java

Tags: java, android

I have implemented plattysoft particle system (https://github.com/plattysoft/Leonids) into my project. I am using the sample code for the confetti example.  But my 'image' that is a particle is just staying in the top left corner.   I am using the exact same code from the example.  Their isn't no errors or anything.

Here is the java code

```
 new ParticleSystem(this,80, R.drawable.red_box_test, 10000)
                .setSpeedModuleAndAngleRange(0f, 0.1f, 180, 180)
                .setRotationSpeed(144)
                .setAcceleration(0.000017f, 90)
                .emit(findViewById(R.id.emiter_top_left), 8);
```

Here is the .xml code

```
  <View android:id="@+id/emiter_top_left"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
```

I do get a warning, on the gravity. The warning says 'use start, and not left to ensure correct behavior'.

Answer (score 0):

What they mean here is that instead of `android:layout_gravity="top|left"` you should use `"top|start"`. The difference being that `"start"` is left when Right-to-Left is disabled, and right when RTL is enabled.